# How to add a new sheet in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am new to VBA coding. I want to populate an excel sheet with different data. The requirement is to pull data into separate sheets of the same Excel. I need to use the same type of code below to maintain the integrity of the entire code.

```
outfile = "c:\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "activedirectorydata.xls"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "**MoActiveDirectoryData**", acFormatXLS, outfile, False
```

I am able to get data from a view/query `MoActiveDirectoryData` into one sheet. How should I go about getting data from another view/query into a different sheet of the same excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, sheets will be created in the same file as long as the table or query that you are exporting has a different name than the sheets that already exist.

```
outfile = "c:\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "activedirectorydata.xls"
''Sheet is called Query1
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Query1", outfile 
''New sheet called Query2
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Query2", outfile
```