# SQL combining data from two rows into a single row when they share a common identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, report

For a report I'm working on I need to combine data from rows in a specific column based on the data they share in a separate column.  All data is from the same table:

```
      ID       |        Name        | 
    10000             Jane Doe            
    10000             John Smith
    50000             Jack Bauer
    50000             Jon Snow
    90000             Jack Bauer
```

I need to somehow combine the Name row together when they share a common ID value:

```
      ID       |        Name        | 
    10000             Jane Doe, John Smith            
    50000             Jack Bauer, Jon Snow
    90000             Jack Bauer
```

The ID is not the `primary key` for this table but it's what I need as the unique value on the report.

I'm mostly self taught and admittedly lacking a perfect `SQL` vocabulary. I can't quite think of how to articulate the code in order to do this.  Any help with the logic would be immensely appreciated!

Dave

Comment: Does this table have a PRIMARY KEY? Also, which RDBMS? Also, see GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  These are different databases and in general a question should be tagged with only the one you are using.

Comment: SQL Server, sorry about that.

Comment: FOR XML would do. Lot of questions about that on Stackoverflow. Will give you a link if I find one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Checking these links now, thank you guys

Comment: @dave814 re your recent question, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432852/how-to-add-a-new-sheet-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: @Remou thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. I guess I'm still getting used to the culture here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(10000,'Jane Doe'),            
(10000,'John Smith'),
(50000,'Jack Bauer'),
(50000,'Jon Snow'),
(90000,'Jack Bauer')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name
              FROM @Table
              WHERE ID = t.ID 
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Names
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║  ID   ║        Names         ║
╠═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 10000 ║ Jane Doe, John Smith ║
║ 50000 ║ Jack Bauer, Jon Snow ║
║ 90000 ║ Jack Bauer           ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```